# Signed driver when started gives, error 577

Tags: windows, driver, windows-server-2008-x64

When I start the driver I have written on Windows Server 2008 x64, it gives `Error 577`.

Windows XP 32-bit works fine, but Windows XP 32-bit doesn't have driver signing restrictions.

Don't know if there's an issue with  my `.inf`? What could be wrong here?

Comment: This is pretty obviously a question for Stack Overflow, so I have no idea why it was migrated here.

Answer (score 5):

577 means your driver's signature is incorrect,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681388(v=vs.85).aspx

How did you sign it? Besides, did you sign it for development and test or for production?

You should strictly follow Microsoft's articles so as to avoid any problem like this,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544865(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 5):

If you are using a Test-Signed Certificate during you development you need to allow the machine, on which you install your driver, to use a test certificate

To do it

Open Command Prompt (Run as Administrator)
Bcdedit.exe -set TESTSIGNING ON
Reboot your machine
To disable it
Bcdedit.exe -set TESTSIGNING OFF
and reboot your machine

More details here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553484%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

That can happen when a driver is properly signed. The specific problem occurs in Windows 7.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2328240#bookmark-letmefixitmyselfalways

Comment: Do you mean "improperly signed", or that it can happen "_even_ when a driver is properly signed"? Also, can you please include details of the resolution in your answer? This will ensure that your answer remains useful even if the linked resource disappears.

Comment: No. I mean that even if a driver is properly signed, there are still scenarios where you will have this problem. There are specific problems for example with Windows 7, x64

Comment: I have the same situation. Driver is signed properly i.e. passed through Microsoft Devportal and has Microsoft Windows Hardware Compatibility Publisher. digital signature. I works perfect on all OS through Win7 to Win10. Though on the Windows 7 machine, which has updates disabled, Driver fails to start due to error 577. Even after I've installed manually all possible certificates update mentioned above. And 'signtool verify' also reports all ok.